# XML rectangles options

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm setting up a game for a project in school in a WPF file. We need to make a sort of flappy bird and we have made the bird and collision detection. We now need to place rectangles in the WPF based on settings from a XML File we have been given. I don't get how we are supposed to get the rectangles in the WPF using XML.

I've tried searching for the problem online and have found no solution. I have read that XML shouldn't be used for these kind of applications but it's demanded by the assignment that we have to do this.

XML File:

```
<GameLevel number="1">
  <Settings>
    <Name>Mania</Name>
    <Dimensions>
      <Width>1200</Width>
      <Height>500</Height>
    </Dimensions>
  </Settings>
  <Blocks>
    <Block Position="100" GapHeight="100" />
    <Block Position="250" GapHeight="20" />
    <Block Position="320" GapHeight="400" />
    <Block Position="540" GapHeight="300" />
    <Block Position="870" GapHeight="50" />
  </Blocks>
</GameLevel>
```

The Read

```
private void ReadXmlFile()
{
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     xmlDoc.Load(@"XMLConfig.xml"); //laad xmlbestand in xmlDoc
     XmlNodeList ListNodes = 
     xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Employees/Employee"); //Zoek nodes
     foreach (XmlNode Rectangles in ListNodes)
     {
     string empId = Rectangles["ID"].InnerText; //Selecteer ID node per Employee
     }
}
```

Edit: I'm aware that the Node isn't completely finished so no need to point that out

Comment: can you show something of your xaml-Code? for example the control you need to add the Rectangles to?

Comment: *I've tried searching for the problem online ...* - seriously? In WPF, you can put Rectangle objects into a Panel. e.g. a Canvas.

Comment: @Clemens I know we can place the objects in the canvas but the assignment we were given strictly specifies that we have to use XML for giving the Rectangles their properties

Comment: Sure, read the rectangle *data* from XML, then put appropriate Rectangles on a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to display a group of boxes on screen in a WPF application is to expose the box coordinates from a ViewModel and then have the XAML render the co-ordinates as rectangles in a Canvas object.

The WPF View will have its DataContext property bound to a ViewModel that exposes a List property called Blocks or something else equally descriptive. This will be bound to an ItemsControl that has its ItemHost property set to a Canvas, with each item having it's X,Y,Width and Height properties determined by values in the XML settings which you've deserialised.

The XAML representation is described in the XAML section below, while the more useful method of deserialising an XML file to be used by a ViewModel in rendering the View can be found in the XmlGameConfiguration class below, which makes use of the XmlSerializer and the various XmlXXX attributes to deserialise your xml file.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="SO56164654.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO56164654"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SO56164654.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type viewModel:LevelViewModel}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="Black"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentLevel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class LevelViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<BlockViewModel> Blocks { get; }
}

    public class BlockViewModel
{
    public LevelBlock _model { get; set; }

    public BlockViewModel(LevelBlock model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return _model.Position; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return _model.Position; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return _model.GapHeight; }
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get { return _model.GapHeight; }
    }
}
```

**Model objects**

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Game
{
    [XmlArray("Levels")]
    public List<GameLevel> Levels { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "GameLevel", Namespace = "")]
public class GameLevel
{
    [XmlAttribute("number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public GameLevelSettings Settings { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Blocks")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Block")]
    public List<LevelBlock> Blocks { get; set; }

}

public class GameLevelDimensions
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
}

public class GameLevelSettings
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GameLevelDimensions Dimensions { get; set; }
}

public class LevelBlock
{
    [XmlAttribute("Position")]
    public int Position { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("GapHeight")]
    public int GapHeight { get; set; }
}

internal class XmlGameConfiguration : IGameConfiguration
{
    private const string ConfigFileName = "game.config";

    public XmlGameConfiguration(string configFilePath)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(configFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Game));
            Game = (Game) ser.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    public XmlGameConfiguration() : this(ConfigFileName)
    {}

    public Game Game { get; private set; }
}
```